# What software can I use to *move* pictures from my wife's iPhone to a Windows laptop?

Tags: windows, images, ios, file-management

My wife has an iPhone 4s and a Windows 8.1 laptop. When I plug the phone in, iTunes pops up. As far as I can tell, iTunes tries to sync with the phone but it doesn't remove photos from the phone after syncing.

When I try to move files from the iPhone to the laptop using Windows Explorer or the Import Pictures wizard built into Windows, the pictures are copied to the laptop but they are not deleted from the iPhone. In order to delete the photos from the iPhone, it seems that I have to delete them one-by-one using the phone's Gallery app.

Is there some software that allows me to *move* photos from the phone to a Windows laptop in one easy step?

Comment: What i do is open iphone from windows explorer and find photos and movies which are mostly in in folders like 8CMXLX and i move them manually ( select all in folder, press shift key while moving files to a folder in laptop, or simply cut and paste). If you try to move folder itself probably it wont let you, so only files.

Comment: Thanks; when you did this, did it actually delete them from the iPhone? I think I already tried this, and it copied them instead of moving them, whether I used cut & paste or shift+drag & drop (move). I'll try again, but as far as I can tell, I cannot use Windows Explorer to move or delete photos from an iPhone 4S.

Comment: It does if you cut and paste. You probably just copied them. In case it fails, i will look into some programs for you if i can find.

Comment: @ouzture I definitely tried to cut and paste the top-level DCIM folder, but I don't recall whether I tried cutting and pasting from within the seemingly randomly-named subfolders. I'll have to give it another shot.